# Swift, can I set a background fetch for a part of the day?

Tags: ios, swift, background, fetch

Can I set the time in the day when I allow the background fetch?
Like all the days, no background fetch allowed but in peak hours, from 6 pm to 8 pm, my application will allow background fetch every UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum (or whatever).

I can only set background fetch frequently (each hour or whatever) and not for a period of the day (or the week, or the month ...).

If someone has an answer or an idea or the beginning of one, I will be really thankful.

Have a good day!

Comment: You cannot. The system will decide when to call background fetch anyways, developers only have control over the mininum interval between background fetches, nothing else.

Comment: no you cant, you set a min interval and thats it, the operating system itself determines when to trigger a background fetch based on various bits of information. you could try a silent remote notification to tell it to fetch but if the app is terminated, then it wont fire

Comment: Really, I can do a silent remote notification to tell it to do a background fetch ? That's exactly what I need, but does it work when the app is in the background ? 
(I want this only in the background not when the app is terminated)

Comment: Yes, push notifications work even when your app is in the background. When a silent push notification is received the system wakes your app and your app has 30seconds to handle the notification.

Comment: Thank you! I know how to handle silent remote notification but how do I send them to the app ? Like if it's 8 am, send silent remote notification! I can't find an answer...

Comment: @AdamPerea if the app has been killed by iOS then the silent push notification cannot be delivered because the app is not running. Likewise if the user has swipe closed / killed the app then the silent push notification will also not be able to wake the app until the app has been at least relaunched by the user and then put into background or unless the user has restarted iOS.